# How to use RxJava to wait the end of two lists of Retrofit requests

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

Let me describe my situation:

- I want to register new records via an API.
- I want to update some records via an API.
- I need to be notified when all of these requests have finished, to start another task.

Specifically I have two `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Report> createdReports = myHelper.getOfflineCreatedReports();
ArrayList<Report> editedReports = myHelper.getOfflineEditedReports();
```

Each report can use methods to get `Observable` instances from my ApiService (Retrofit implementation).

```
        Observable<NewReportResponse> createdReportsObs = Observable.from(createdReports) // .just() != .from()
            .flatMap(new Func1<Report, Observable<NewReportResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<NewReportResponse> call(Report report) {
                    return report.postToServer();
                }
            });

    Observable<NewReportResponse> editedReportsObs = Observable.from(editedReports)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Report, Observable<NewReportResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<NewReportResponse> call(Report report) {
                    return report.updateInServer();
                }
            });
```

I am using the `flatMap` operator to get one Observable for each report.

But I am not sure how to wait until all of the requests have finished.

I was thinking in using the `zip` operator.

```
Observable.zip(createdReportsObs, editedReportsObs, new Func2<NewReportResponse, NewReportResponse, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(NewReportResponse justOneResponse, NewReportResponse justOneResponse2) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately I saw some examples where `zip` is used to create pairs of Observables.

Please suggest me what operator I can use to achieve it. Or how to do it using rxJava with a different approach.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is my way. May not best practice.

```
Observable.merge(createdReportsObs, editedReportsObs)
          .toList()
          .flatMap(Observable::from)
          .xxx //Now they are completed, do what you want
          .subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference using ```subscribe``` directly after ```merge```?

Comment: You can do more than `doOnCompleted` and `doOnError`. After this operate, even `doOnNext` is called after they are completed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using RxJava 2? If so you can use the new completable api. This is assuming you don't need to know any of the server results, just need to wait for them to complete.

```
Completeable.merge(createdReportsObs.toCompleteable(),
                   editedReportsObs.toCompleteable())
            .subscribe()
```